# How to clear saved autofill data of browser in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Does any one know how to clear all saved autofill data of browser in Asp.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an attribute "autocomplete" to your inputs and set it to "off".

For example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

If you want it to apply on all inputs you can add this attribute to the form tag.

Comment: thats what i was looking for now i understood that we can do this through vb coading also like textbox1.attributes.add("autocomplete","off")

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will automatically repopulate the posted values of a form. To clear them out you will have to set the values to empty strings/0 yourself.

Comment: You are saying what is also correct but what i wanted that my friend just told me to use and it is also working i.e textbox1.attributes.add("autocomplete","off")

Comment: @Mayur - I can't guess at what your friend told you. Why not post that as an answer to your question, so people can see your solution in the future when reading this question?

Comment: but i don't know how this is working do you know how this works

Comment: @Mayur - how _what_ works? The solution from your friend? Adding an answer on SO?

Comment: yes,do you know how this statements works what does it means? textbox1.attributes.add("autocomplete","off")

Comment: @Mayur - No, I don't, not without seeing all the code on the page and understanding what you are trying to do. At a guess, I would say there is javascript/css that look for this attribute and change behavior.